AttributeError in TCN Layer when Building Model on Google Colab: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'as_list'
I am doing a project that needs to use Temporal Convolutional Network and I found a package that supports building this conveniently: https://github.com/philipperemy/keras-tcn
Below is the code that I am using to define the architecture of the TCN model.
!pip install keras-tcn

from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Softmax, Lambda
from tcn import TCN

# Create the Input Layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(20, 225))

# First TCN Layer - parameters based on the tcn.py file
tcn_layer_1 = TCN(nb_filters=64,
                  kernel_size=3,
                  nb_stacks=1,
                  dilations=(1, 2, 4, 8),
                  padding='causal',
                  use_skip_connections=True,
                  return_sequences=True, # Important: Return sequences for stacked TCN layers
                  dropout_rate=0.05,
                  activation='relu',
                  use_batch_norm=False,
                  use_layer_norm=False)(input_layer)

# Second TCN Layer - similar parameters as the first layer
tcn_layer_2 = TCN(nb_filters=64,
                  kernel_size=3,
                  nb_stacks=1,
                  dilations=(1, 2, 4, 8),
                  padding='causal',
                  use_skip_connections=True,
                  return_sequences=False, # Final TCN layer, no need to return sequences
                  dropout_rate=0.05,
                  activation='relu',
                  use_batch_norm=False,
                  use_layer_norm=False)(tcn_layer_1)

# Dense Layer to further process the TCN output
dense_layer = Dense(128, activation='relu')(tcn_layer_2)

# Softmax Output Layer for classification
output_layer = Dense(len(gloss_list), activation='softmax')(dense_layer)

# Compile the model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Print the model summary to verify the architecture
model.summary()

This error below pops up after running the above block of code.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3a050a142399> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 
      8 # First TCN Layer - parameters based on the tcn.py file
----> 9 tcn_layer_1 = TCN(nb_filters=64,
     10                   kernel_size=3,
     11                   nb_stacks=1,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tcn/tcn.py in build(self, input_shape)
    314             self.output_slice_index = -1  # causal case.
    315         self.slicer_layer = Lambda(lambda tt: tt[:, self.output_slice_index, :], name='Slice_Output')
--> 316         self.slicer_layer.build(self.build_output_shape.as_list())
    317 
    318     def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'as_list'

The weirdest thing is I can actually run this code on my Macbook M1 Pro.
The summary of the model is printed out when I run the code on my local machine.
I have tried to look inside the code of the keras-tcn package but found nothing. The error comes from the method below of the TCN class, specifically from the last line of code self.slicer_layer.build(self.build_output_shape.as_list()). As I understand, the self.build_output_shape is set as a tuple input_shape at the start of the method. For the code to work out, I think (actually GPT-4o) self.build_output_shape will be changed into a TensorShape object at the line self.build_output_shape = self.residual_blocks[-1].res_output_shape. But it seems like the object's type didn't change, which cause the error. Again, the weirdest thing is this happens only on Google Colab, not on my local machine.
def build(self, input_shape):

        # member to hold current output shape of the layer for building purposes
        self.build_output_shape = input_shape

        # list to hold all the member ResidualBlocks
        self.residual_blocks = []
        total_num_blocks = self.nb_stacks * len(self.dilations)
        if not self.use_skip_connections:
            total_num_blocks += 1  # cheap way to do a false case for below

        for s in range(self.nb_stacks):
            for i, d in enumerate(self.dilations):
                res_block_filters = self.nb_filters[i] if isinstance(self.nb_filters, list) else self.nb_filters
                self.residual_blocks.append(ResidualBlock(dilation_rate=d,
                                                          nb_filters=res_block_filters,
                                                          kernel_size=self.kernel_size,
                                                          padding=self.padding,
                                                          activation=self.activation_name,
                                                          dropout_rate=self.dropout_rate,
                                                          use_batch_norm=self.use_batch_norm,
                                                          use_layer_norm=self.use_layer_norm,
                                                          use_weight_norm=self.use_weight_norm,
                                                          kernel_initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                                          name='residual_block_{}'.format(len(self.residual_blocks))))
                # build newest residual block
                self.residual_blocks[-1].build(self.build_output_shape)
                self.build_output_shape = self.residual_blocks[-1].res_output_shape

        # this is done to force keras to add the layers in the list to self._layers
        for layer in self.residual_blocks:
            self.__setattr__(layer.name, layer)

        self.output_slice_index = None
        if self.padding == 'same':
            time = self.build_output_shape.as_list()[1]
            if time is not None:  # if time dimension is defined. e.g. shape = (bs, 500, input_dim).
                self.output_slice_index = int(self.build_output_shape.as_list()[1] / 2)
            else:
                # It will known at call time. c.f. self.call.
                self.padding_same_and_time_dim_unknown = True

        else:
            self.output_slice_index = -1  # causal case.
        self.slicer_layer = Lambda(lambda tt: tt[:, self.output_slice_index, :], name='Slice_Output')
        self.slicer_layer.build(self.build_output_shape.as_list())


I downgraded the tensorflow version in Colab it runs, Colab usually installs  version 2.17.0
I used this code to downgrade it
#!pip install tensorflow==2.12  # install tensorflow 2.12
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version)
